# how to configure django to run migration files in a specific order

Tags: python, django

I have a project which requires me to insert initial data into the database on migration. Now everything works fine except that I need to tell django to insert some specific data linked with a migration file before running another.

For example, lets say I have two migration files, A and B, and each is attached to models ModelA and ModelB respectively. The migration for A works fine, but for B, I am automatically generating its SQL statement which requires me to use `ModelA.objects.get(id=id)` while generating the statements, but I get an error `ModelA.DoesNotExist`, which means migration A hasn't been saved.

Is there a way I can ensure the data inserted by the migration A has been saved before proceeding to run migration B?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-files Use `dependencies`?

Answer (score 1):

As @tom-dalton mentioned the way to go is through dependencies.

You can see an example of a dependency in a migration file [here in the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#migration-files).

They are written in the following format:

```
from django.db import migrations, models

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [("your_app_name", "migration_file_name")]

    operations = [
        # Migration operations here
    ]
```

You can find the migration file name by looking in the migrations folder of your project.

Finally you need to follow the [data migration process](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/migrations/#data-migrations) to access ModelA data in your new migration.

Comment: You're welcome. Please accept the answer if it was helpful.